# Centering Ascii Graphics Python

Tags: python

So I read that to print ascii graphics you need to use the following print format:

```
print(  
"""


"""  
)
```

However, `""" """".center(width)` doesn't work with this, and I want my picture to be centered in the terminal. How can I achieve this?

Example attached for clarity: 
[image: Example] (Notice that ascii picture isnt centered whereas an ordinary string was centered)

Comment: Can you include a sample in your question of something that doesn't get centered?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, I think you want to loop over `s.splitlines()` and call `center` on each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`""" """` are multiline strings - they include "natural" newlines without resorting to `text \n more text \n more more text`.

If you want to center something, create a list of lines (or split your `"""..."""` on `'\n'`) and prefix ist with enough spaces to center it inside your output width:

```
def padToCenter(l:list,w:int)->str:
    """Manual centering"""
    padding =  ' '*(w//2) # a 1 char line would need at most w/2 spaces in front
    parts = [ padding[0: (w-len(p))//2+1]+p for p in l]
    return '\n'.join(parts)


def padToCenter2(l:list,w:int)->str:
    return '\n'.join('-'+x.center(w)+'-' for x in l)

centerMe = ["this", "is some different" , "lenghty", "data that should be", "centered"]
print(padToCenter(centerMe,60))
print("")
print(padToCenter2(centerMe,60))
```

Output (line-ends/starts adorned with "-":

```
# manual
-                             this-
-                      is some different-
-                           lenghty-
-                     data that should be-
-                           centered-

# .center()
-                            this                            -
-                     is some different                      -
-                          lenghty                           -
-                    data that should be                     -
-                          centered                          -
```

---

*Edit*: Multiline Example:

```
multi = """    
#             BBQ-Service:              #
#  .        _.-----.  \.-./       . .   #
#  \`-.._,-' .-. .-.`-' ``-.  _,-'.'`.  #
#   `-.____,-. `:. `.-'-._.O-:_ .:'., | #
#             `-" `-"          `-.__.'  #
#                                       #
"""

print("-")
print(padToCenter(multi.splitlines(),60))
```

Output:

```
          #             BBQ-Service:              #
          #  .        _.-----.  \.-./       . .   #
          #  \`-.._,-' .-. .-.`-' ``-.  _,-'.'`.  #
          #   `-.____,-. `:. `.-'-._.O-:_ .:'., | #
          #             `-" `-"          `-.__.'  #
          #                                       #
```

---

*Edit*: You can prepad lines to the same length using:

```
def padRight(l:list)->list:
    maxLength = max(len(x) for x in l)
    return [ x.ljust(maxLength) for x in l]

lines =[ "123","12345","123456789012345"]

print (lines)          
print(padRight(lines))
```

Output:

```
['123', 
 '12345', 
 '123456789012345']

['123            ', 
 '12345          ', 
 '123456789012345']
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, thanks. However, instead of a list of words, I have something like:  
"""  
art goes here  
""". So I am not able to use that function.    
  EDIT: splitlines() function is just for this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Συλχαν You are ... split the `""" your text here """` multiline at `'\n'`. something like `mylines = """ ..... """.splitlines()` creates the list of multiple lines. Problem: your art needs to be  all lines having same width to allow for centering,.

Comment: Is there a way to accommodate for that problem too, in case the art doesn't have the same width on all lines?

Comment: @Συλχαν Prepad the lines to equal length.